# Creating multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this: `$test = array(20, 30, 40);`

And I want to set a multi-dimension array with using these values: `$example[20][30][40] = 'string'`

How can I do this?

Note: "20, 30, 40" just an example, my program will print some integers, and I want to set a multi-dimension array with these values and it can be more than 3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it that way:

```
$example[$test[0]][$test[1]][$test[2]] = 'string'
```

Or if the size of the array is variable you will need to do a recursive function to fill up your array.

```
function fill_up($content, $value){
    $index = array_shift($content);
    if(count($content)){
        return array($index => fill_up($content, $value));
    } else {
        return array($index => $value);
    }
}

$example = array(20,30,40);
$value = 'test';
var_dump(fill_up($example, $value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write :

```
 $example[19][29][39] = 'string'
```

Do not forget that the first element is 0 and not 1. This should work.

Comment: I couldn't explain my question. :/ It must be automatic, I have already written some snippet.

Comment: Explain more because we do not understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

EXAMPLE:

`$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);`

echo $arr["foo"]; // bar
echo $arr[12];    // 1

EXPLANATION:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates
>   values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be
>   treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a
>   map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array
>   values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also
>   possible.

This can be expanded to n-dimensions.  It's equivalent to an array within an array:

2-D ARRAY EXAMPLE:

`$arr = array("somearray" => array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42));`

echo $arr["somearray"][6];    // 5
echo $arr["somearray"][13];   // 9
echo $arr["somearray"]["a"];  // 42

'Hope that helps!

Comment: unfortunately, it isn't relevant to my question. :(

Answer (score 0):

As 14moose seems to have been getting at, you can't make an empty array in PHP. It's not really an array. It's a map. You could certainly make a ridiculous multidimensional map using those input values, but that seems.. entirely useless.

Comment: actually I'm writing an unlimited category plugin for my CMS. It sounds like an useless idea in this question but i will use this for listing my all categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$example = array();
$test = array(20, 30, 40);
foreach($test as $key=>$value)
{
   $example[$value] = $test;
}
print_r($example);exit;

?>
```